# Error al mostrar vue.js Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy empezando con Vue.js. Tengo mi archivo index.html y mi archivo index.js.

Me da un error al mostrar el archivo index.html en el navegador.

### Archivo index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>LearnVue.js</title>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
<div id="app-2">
    <span v-bind:tittle="message">
    Hover your mouse over me for a few seconds
    to see my dynamically bound title!
    </span>
</div>
<div id="app-3">
    <span v-if="seen">Now you see me</span>
</div>

<div id="app-4">
    <ol>
        <li v-for="all in all">
            {{all.text}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="app-5">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Archivo index.js

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }

});

var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data: {
        message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
    }
});

var app3 = new Vue({
   el: '#app-3',
    data: {
       seen: true
    }
});

var app4 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-4',
    data: {
        all: [
            {text: 'Learn JavaScript'},
            {text: 'Learn Ruby on Rails'}
        ]
    }
});

var app5 = new Vue({
    el: 'app-5',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    },
    methods: {
        reserveMessage: function () {
            this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: aun sigues teniendo el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Este error sale por no hacer referencia al archivo `js` de **Vue**.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Luego puedes hacer uso:

```
<script>
      var demo = new Vue({
          el: '#demo',
          data: {
              message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
          }
      })
</script>
```

Para el error que tienes intenta cambiar de posición las referencias `js` de esta manera

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Era cambiar el orden de los enlaces.